# Timeseries function

Tags: pandas

I've got a  dataframe which looks something like this:

Column1
315349655

315349655

315349655

315349655

It's more rows and how to write a function   which will check if any value is bigger than the first row and also show where are these values are located.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll create a dummy dataframe for this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Column1": [random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(10)]},
    index=[(pd.to_datetime("today") + pd.DateOffset(days=i)).date() for i in range(10)],
)
>>> df
            Column1
2022-02-24        3
2022-02-25        8
2022-02-26        1
2022-02-27        6
2022-02-28        2
2022-03-01        8
2022-03-02        2
2022-03-03       10
2022-03-04        1
2022-03-05        4
```

To get the first value, we can use `.loc` with the first value of the index and the column that you want:

```
>>> first_value = df.loc[df.index[0] ,"Column1"]
>>> first_value
3
```

To get the rows where we have a higher value than the value in the first row, we can use this comparison, thanks to pandas vectorization:

```
>>> row_has_higher_value_than_first_value = df["Column1"] > first_value
>>> row_has_higher_value_than_first_value
2022-02-24    False
2022-02-25     True
2022-02-26    False
2022-02-27     True
2022-02-28    False
2022-03-01     True
2022-03-02    False
2022-03-03     True
2022-03-04    False
2022-03-05     True
Name: Column1, dtype: bool
```

Finally, we can use that selector to find the indexes where the condition is met:

```
>>> indexes_of_higher_values = df.index[row_has_higher_value_than_first_value]
>>> indexes_of_higher_values
Index([2022-02-25, 2022-02-27, 2022-03-01, 2022-03-03, 2022-03-05], dtype='object')
```